# Array in for loop gives array index out of range exception

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
ShopButton[] allButtons = FindObjectsOfType<ShopButton> ();

for (int i = 0; i < allButtons.Length; i++) 
{
    allButtons [i].UpdateButtonState ((GameDataManager.publicInstance.skinAvailability & 1 << allButtons [i - 1].ninjaNumber) == 1 << allButtons [i - 1].ninjaNumber);
}
```

When I run it this code gives me an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Because on the first loop, `i` will be 0 and `i - 1` will be -1, which is not a valid index for an array.

Comment: Change fro loop to start at 1 instead of zero : for (int i = 1; i < allButtons.Length; i++)

Comment: i have already tried  i-1 and like @IanH. said i-1 results in the index being -1 which results in the same error...

Comment: @jdweng what you suggested worked so if you put your comment into an answer and explain why i have to start at 1 and then use i-1 instead of starting at 0 and just using i, your answer will be happily accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is because of the first index that causes a problem.
if i starts with 1 then i-1 will be 0 and therefore the index 0 exists in array allbuttons.
Clearly : if starting i is `0`, then `i-1` will be `-1`; this will cause `index out of range exception` because all arrays start with index `0` and have no index -1. ;

Starting with `i = 1` the error will be solved because then `i-1` will be `0` which is in range of indexes of any array.

change part of loop  to :

```
for (int i = 1; i < allButtons.Length; i++)
```

Comment: BTW anyone who offers a better explanation will have their answer accepted instead of this one as it gives a very limited explanation (no offense, I am still very thankful for your help

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, although it does not address what i was doing as in my code I was starting with i= 0 but never used i - 1...